# How to convert individual char from a table of char into an int

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Hello I don't know how to proceed :(

Anybody can tell me how to convert a char to int from a table of char separate by commas ?

```
char mesg[] = "3,1,0,500';
```

I have an array of char separate by commas, and i want obtain each integer separately, so i want display each integer individualy

```
...
if(mesg[i]==data_separator)
    {
       digit = atoi(buffer[i]);
       printf(" number %d : %d",i,number );
       ...
    }
```

Terminal :

```
number 1 : 3
number 2 : 1
number 3 : 0
number 4 : 500
```

Thank you so much for your responses !

Comment: Is this C or C++? And whichever it is, never use atoi().

Comment: `digit = atoi(mesg[i+1]);` should work. BTW why C++ tag?

Comment: C != C++ and a solution for one language may not work in the other. In general, you should tag only the language you are writing/compiling.

Comment: I can't spot a question here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Try with sscanf(mesg, "%d",&number)

Comment: Yes i've made a mistake when i've tag the post, sorry about that

Comment: @cenixu So WHICH is it?

Comment: Sorry it's C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char mesg[] = "3,1,0,500";
    char* next = mesg;
    while (next)
    {
        int digit;
        if (sscanf_s(next, "%d", &digit) == 0)
            break;

        cout << digit << endl;

        next = strchr(next, ',');
        if (next) 
            next++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```